# Unable to connect to RDS Aurora DB locally

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a somewhat basic understanding of Cloud Architecture and thought I would try to spin up a PostgreSQL DB in Terraform. I am using Secret Manager to store credentials...

```
resource "random_password" "password" {
  length           = 16
  special          = true
  override_special = "_%@"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secret" {
  name = "admin"
  description = "Database admin user password"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "version" {
  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret.id
  secret_string = <<EOF
   {
    "username": "db_user",
    "password": "${random_password.password.result}"
   }
EOF
}

locals {
  db_credentials = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.credentials.secret_string)
}
```

And an AuoraDB instance which *should* be publically accessible with the following code

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "cluster-demo" {
  cluster_identifier = "aurora-cluster-demo"
  database_name = "test_db"
  master_username = local.db_credentials["username"]
  master_password = local.db_credentials["password"]
  port = 5432
  engine = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version = "12.7"
  apply_immediately = true
  skip_final_snapshot  = "true"
}

// child instances inherit the same config
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instance" {
  identifier         = "aurora-cluster-demo-instance"
  cluster_identifier = aws_rds_cluster.cluster-demo.id
  engine             = aws_rds_cluster.cluster-demo.engine
  engine_version     = aws_rds_cluster.cluster-demo.engine_version
  instance_class     = "db.r4.large"
  publicly_accessible = true   # Remove 
}
```

When I `terraform apply` this, everything gets created as expected, but when I run `psql -h <ENDPOINT_TO_CLUSTER>` I get prompted to enter the password for `admin`. Going to the secrets portal copying the password and entering yields:

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "admin"
```

Similarily, if I try:

`psql --username=db_user --host=<ENDPOINT_TO_CLUSTER> --port=5432`

I am prompted as expected, to enter the password for `db_user`, which yields:

```
psql: FATAL:  database "db_user" does not exist
```

### Edit 1

secrets.tf

```
resource "random_password" "password" {
  length           = 16
  special          = true
  override_special = "_%@"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secret" {
  name = "admin"
  description = "Database admin user password"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "version" {
  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret.id
  secret_string = <<EOF
   {
    "username": "db_user",
    "password": "${random_password.password.result}"
   }
EOF
}
```

database.tf

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "cluster-demo" {
  cluster_identifier = "aurora-cluster-demo"
  database_name = "test_db"
  master_username = "db_user"
  master_password = random_password.password.result
  port = 5432
  engine = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version = "12.7"
  apply_immediately = true
  skip_final_snapshot  = "true"
}

// child instances inherit the same config
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instance" {
  identifier         = "aurora-cluster-demo-instance"
  cluster_identifier = aws_rds_cluster.cluster-demo.id
  engine             = aws_rds_cluster.cluster-demo.engine
  engine_version     = aws_rds_cluster.cluster-demo.engine_version
  instance_class     = "db.r4.large"
  publicly_accessible = true   # Remove 
}

output "db_user" {
  value = aws_rds_cluster.cluster-demo.master_username
}
```

Comment: @JuanFontes the `psql` command in the question is perfectly fine. It's just using the long-form arguments instead of the short-form that you are using. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html

Comment: The database name in the Terraform code is `test_db`.  If we don't specify the database name explicitly, `psql` will try to use the `--username` as the database name. Correctly would be in this case to have the following: `psql --username=db_user --host=<ENDPOINT_TO_CLUSTER> --port=5432 --dbname=test_db`.

Comment: Also, the main problem with the Terraform code is that there is no mention of networking and security groups anywhere. While, I think the OP is does already have the port `5432` opened on the default security group for the default VPC, this may not be the case anywhere.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi if there were any network or security issues the error would have been a network timeout. The username/password errors they are seeing is coming from the database server, which means connectivity is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a data lookup named `data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.credentials` but you don't show the Terraform code for that. Terraform is going to do that lookup **before** it updates the `aws_secretsmanager_secret_version`. So the username and password it is configuring the DB with is going to be pulled from the previous version of the secret, not the new version you are creating when you run `apply`.

You should never have both a `data` and a `resource` in your Terraform that refer to the same thing. Always use the `resource` if you have it, and only use `data` for things that aren't being managed by Terraform.

Since you have the resource itself available in your Terraform code (and also the `random_password` resource), you shouldn't be using a `data` lookup at all. If you pull the value from one of the resources, then Terraform will handle the  order of creation/updates correctly.

For example:

```
locals {
  db_credentials = jsondecode(aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.version.secret_string)
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "cluster-demo" {
  master_username = local.db_credentials["username"]
  master_password = local.db_credentials["password"]
```

Or just simplify it and get rid of the `jsondecode` step:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "cluster-demo" {
  master_username = "db_user"
  master_password = random_password.password.result
```

I also suggest adding a few Terraform outputs to help you diagnose this type of issue. The following will let you see exactly what username and password Terraform applied to the database:

```
output "db_user" {
  value = aws_rds_cluster.cluster-demo.master_username
}

output "db_password" {
  value = aws_rds_cluster.cluster-demo.master_password
  sensitive = true
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question. I wasn't able to output the password unless marking it as sensitive so didn't see much point in keeping it.

Comment: You just have to add a `sensitive = true` to the output. Why don't you see a point in that?

Comment: It looks like you just edited your question to copy my suggestions in there. What happened after you applied that and then tried to connect to the database?

Comment: I was able to connect @Mark B. Thank you